# Nginx regular expressions

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting

I'm trying to do the following rewrites:

maindomain.com/country/everythingExceptWork to redirect to country url

```
location ~ ^/france(?:/(?!work))(?:(.*))$ {
return         301 https://www.maindomain.com/fr/france/;
}
```

maindomain.com/anycountry/works to redirect to a single url

```
  location ~ ^/(spain|italy|france)/work$ {
  return         301 https://www.maindomain.com/en/works/;
  }
```

The issue is that when i test maindomain.com/country/ it works, but if i test it maindomain.com/country (without the last slash) it will use the default rule, this issue started when i changed:

```
this:      location ~ ^/spain(?:/(.*))?$ {
for this:  location ~ ^/spain(?:/(?!work))(?:(.*))$ {
```

NGINX CONF:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name maindomain.com;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
 listen 443 ssl;
 server_name maindomain.com;
 ssl on;

  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;
  ssl_dhparam  /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;

#reverse proxy
#Default
  location / {
  return         301 https://www.maindomain.com;
  }

#Work ALL COUNTRIES
  location ~ ^/(spain|italy|france)/work$ {
  return         301 https://www.maindomain.com/en/works/;
  }

#France
  location ~ ^/france(?:/(?!work))(?:(.*))$ {
  return         301 https://www.maindomain.com/fr/france/;
  }


#Spain
  location ~ ^/spain(?:/(?!work))(?:(.*))$ {
  return         301 https://www.maindomain.com/es/spain/;
  }

#Italy
  location ~ ^/italy(?:/(?!work))(?:(.*))$ {
  return         301 https://www.maindomain.com/en/italy/;
  }

}
```

What i'm missing on this change to include country with or without slash ?

```
this:      location ~ ^/spain(?:/(.*))?$ {
for this:  location ~ ^/spain(?:/(?!work))(?:(.*))$ {
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last question sign on the `location ~ ^/spain(?:/(.*))?$` regex makes the second slash and all the following an optional part. To left the slash optional you need to change your regex from

```
location ~ ^/spain(?:/(?!work))(?:(.*))$ { ... }
```

to

```
location ~ ^/spain(?:/(?!work).*)?$ { ... }
```

To preserve first capture group, use

```
location ~ ^/spain(?:/(?!work)(.*))?$ { ... }
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ivan, that worked! much appreciated